# Area of a weird ellipse shape.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

A propeller has the shape shown below. The boundary of the internal hole is given by $r = a + b\cos(4α)$ where $a > b >0$. The external boundary of the propeller is given by $r = c + d\cos(3α)$ where $c - d > a + b$ and $d > 0$.

Calculate the total area of the propeller as shown by the shaded region and calculate the average temperature of the propeller, given by $T (r, α) = C/r$, where $C$ is a constant.

[image]

Have absolutely no idea how to solve this.

Comment: You need to integrate $c + d\cos 3\alpha$ and the other curve in polar coordinates and subtract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**This answer was dead wrong.** Unfortunately it cannot be deleted. See my new answer below.)

Comment: So Im assuming, you have to integrate the first equation for the outer boundary and minus the inner boundary ?... But thank you good sir, this really helped alot!

Comment: Isn't the area element in polar coordinates $dA=rdrd\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**; my previous answer was wrong.

The area element in polar coordinates is given by
$${\rm d(area)}=r\>{\rm d}(r,\phi)\ .$$
Therefore the area $A$ of your propeller is given by
$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{a+b\cos(4\phi)}^{c+d\cos(3\phi)} r\>dr\ d\phi\>,$$
and the "heat content" $H$ computes to
$$H=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{a+b\cos(4\phi)}^{c+d\cos(3\phi)} {C\over r} r\>dr\ d\phi\ .$$
Finally the average temperture is obtained as
$$T_{\rm mean}={H\over A}\ .$$
The following figure shows the mathematica output for this problem. Your $C$ has been replaced by $p$ therein.

[image]

Comment: @user1337: I was out of my mind when I wrote that answer. I have tried to delete it, but didn't succeed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I used, your previous answer seemed to complicated to do by hand, but thanks anyway, it put me in the right direction.