# Finding an area of a propeller using double integration? Attempted, please help! :(

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

The boundary of the internal hole is given by $r = a + b\cos(4α)$ where $a > b >0$. The external boundary of the propeller is given by $r = c + d\cos(3α)$ where $c - d > a + b$ and $d > 0$.

1/Calculate the total area of the propeller as shown by the shaded region

2/calculate the average temperature of the propeller, given by $T (r, α) = C/r$, where $C$ is a constant.

3/Evaluate the average temperature numerically for a=3, b=1, c=12, d=5 and C=250 where distance is in cm and temperature is Celsius

[image]

I got an idea but don't know if it's right and when I ask my friend none of them know how to :(
Are you suppose to integrate $r = c + d\cos(3α)$ then minus the hole $r = a + b\cos(4α)$ ?

$${1\over2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{p+q\cos(n\phi)} r^2\>dr\ d\phi\>,\qquad {1\over2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{p+q\cos(n\phi)}{C\over r}\> r^2\>dr\ d\phi\ .$$
since the area of the propeller in polar coordinate is:
$${\rm d(area)}={1\over2} r^2{\rm d}(r,\phi)\ .$$

If someone help me solve it, it would make my day because I have no idea how to do it! :(
I'll thank you if you could solve it! Pretty please.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800179/area-of-a-weird-ellipse-shape/800226#800226

Comment: wow thank you! your work is amazing and so clear really appreciate your work and effort. Same with @user86418

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: Your strategy of subtracting areas is correct. However, it makes the calculation formally simpler to use
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{r_{1}(\phi)}^{r_{2}(\phi)} r\, dr\, d\phi
  = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \bigl(r_{2}(\phi)^{2} - r_{1}(\phi)^{2}\bigr)\, d\phi
$$
instead of subtracting integrals. (You have an extra factor of $r$ in your integrands.)

Your set-up for the average temperature is on the right track (loosely, your integral represents "the total temperature" once you remove the extra factor of $r$), but you need to divide by the area to get the average temperature.